# Compilation error of embeded code in Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I want to show `Date` with this code:

```
<% var now=System.DateTime.Now; %>
<div id="clock" title="<%=now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>" ></div>
```

but it gives me this error:

> Compilation Error:
>
> ) expected

in second line of my code.

Comment: Try `title='<%=now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>'` with single quotes.

Comment: @Romoku now title become `<%=now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>`.

Comment: Remove the semi colon after your toString,  <%= is equivalent to a response.Write and is just looking for a string value essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi colon after your toString, <%= is equivalent to a response.Write and is just looking for a string value essentially.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "yyyy/MM/dd" with 'yyyy/MM/dd'
Remove ";"

```
<% var now=System.DateTime.Now; %>
<div id="clock" title="<%=now.ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')%>" ></div>
```

Comment: it returns `<%=now.ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')%>` without processing.

Comment: Your quotes are fine all you need to do is remove the semi colon and you should be good,  see this link for explanation of the asp.net tags.  http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the string correctly. Remove the `;` after `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`.

Try this:

```
<div id="clock" title="<%=now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>" ></div>
```

If that doesn't work, then keep the date format in single quote:

```
title="<%=now.ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
```